# How to break if loop and start over from next element in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, break, continue

Following code gets single value as `a` and `b` as pair of values from user and then if in the first pair `B[0,0]<B[0,1]` will skip the first pair and then 2nd condition will continue till the condition is satisfied.

Assume `B=([1,5],[10,3],[4,6],[2,10],[20,11],[2,8])`, Therefore, first pair should be skiped and calculation of 2nd condition is `(10-3)+4=11 since 11>6`  continue to next by using previous answer which is `11` so `(11-6)+2=7` since `7<10` then stop and start over from next pair `[20,11]`. Therefore, since  `[20,11]` satisfies the statement `(20-11)+2=11` and `11>8` it should print index of pair which is `4` but my code prints index `1` as an answer.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(input(), dtype=int)
B=[]
for i in range(a):
    b = np.array(input().split(), dtype=int)
    B.append(b)
B = np.array(B)
for i in range(a):
    if B[i,0]<B[i,1]:
        continue
    if (B[i,0]-B[i,1])+B[i+1,0]>B[i+1,1]: 
        B[i+1,0]=B[i,0]-B[i,1]           
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the whole flow, but `continue` and `break` help for skipping and stopping loops.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: why `1` is not the right answer? it appears to me the condition is true for 1 as well as 4? if you remove the `break` statement you will get `4` also.

Comment: The condition should be right all the way to last pair. Pair 1 satisfies just on step and it stops at pair [2,10], but pair [20,11] satisfies rest of array which in this case is just [2,8]. I removed break and raised with error "index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5"

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down manually with the help of my interactive python terminal.  First I'll replace the top half of your code with

```
B = np.array(([1, 5], [10, 3], [4, 6], [2, 10], [20, 11], [2, 8]))
```

because that is what's relevant.

Now on your first iteration i is set to 0.

```
i = 0
```

The first conditional is:

```
B[i, 0] < B[i, 1]
```

which evaluates to `True`.  So you hit the nested block which reads:

```
continue
```

The flow now goes back to the loop statement and sets i to 1.

```
i = 1
```

Now

```
B[i, 0] < B[i, 1]
```

evaluates to `False`.  So the block with `continue` is skipped and we go to the next line.  An `if` statement with the following condition:

```
(B[i, 0] - B[i, 1]) + B[i + 1, 0] > B[i + 1, 1]
```

According to my python shell this evaluates to `True`.  So we execute the nested block.  Line by line:

```
// This changes some state but is irrelevant to the control flow,
B[i + 1, 0] = B[i , 0] - B[i, 1]

// So the next line is executed.
print(i)
// Since i is currently set to 1, your program prints '1'

// Now the next line is executed
break    
// This ends the execution of the loop completely.  Your code will now terminate.
```

So your code prints 1, as expected.